# Why is $A=([0,1] \times [0,1]) \cap (\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q)$ not closed

Tags: real-analysis

The set  $A=([0,1] \times [0,1]) \cap (\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q)$ is said to be not closed. The way my textbook proves this is:

Consider the sequence $x_n$ where $x_n$ is the $n$-th decimal place of the expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then $(x_n,x_n)$ is a sequence in $A$ that does not converge to a point in $A$.

I don't understand what exactly $(x_n,x_n)$ means. Is that a sequence of points? Also, how exactly is it a sequence in $A$ if it's an irrational number? And why does it converge to a point which is not in $A$?

Comment: Do you mean to say that $A$ is **not** closed?

Comment: A set can't be closed. "Closed" not a property a set has by itself, but rather a property that a _subset_ has. In particular subsets of topological and metric spaces. (Of course, any set is a subset of itself, but in that interpretation, _all_ sets are closed.) In this case, maybe you mean to say "not closed as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ (with the standard topology / metric)".

Comment: @G.Chiusole yes, typo

Comment: Funny how it's a question involving a set, then it's set theory. And yet, involving numbers doesn't make it number theory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term $x_n$, I believe, is defined as truncating the decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. For example $x_2=0.70$. If you continue the sequence, then the limit is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Actually, one way to define the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is to be the $\textit{completion}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is defined to be all Cauchy sequences of rational numbers. This means that when viewing $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$. We can use this reasoning to see that the closure of $A$ is $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, therefore $A$ is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence given by $X_n = (x_n,x_n)$ is a sequence of points in $A$. Its values are in $A$ because they are decimal, so they are rational. Though, the fact that it doesn't converge in a point in $A$ (let's say the topology is induced by $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric) just proves that it isn't closed. An example of a set which is not closed nor open is $[0;1)$. There obviously is sequences of elements in this interval which converges to $1$, so it's not closed, but it's not open either.